# display image path from db to img src using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

so i have an image

```
<div class="portfolio-image" style="height:200px; width:100%;">
   <img id="coverImage" src="" alt="Avatar" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height:200px; width:100%;">
   <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
   <input type="file" id="uploadedCoverImage" style="display: none;">
</div><br>
```

and i use jquery to change the image..

```
$('.fa-cloud-upload').click(function () {
  $('#uploadedCoverImage').trigger('click');
});
```

use this `.trigger('click')` then

```
$('#uploadedCoverImage').change(function (e) {
    var input = e.target;

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadedFiles-0' , input.files[0]);
    formData.append('user_id', user_id);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../../../ajax/user/upload_coverImage.php',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function (results) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var dataURL = reader.result;
      var output = $('#coverImage')[0];
      output.src = dataURL;

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
});
```

the ajax request is fine it saves the image path to my db but my problem is when i it returns `true` supposedly the image path from my db will be displayed on image src tag but what happen is it doesn't display the image from my db.. i think there's something wrong with the filereader but dont know how to solve it.. any idea?

Comment: I think you need to base64 the img and save it in the db.

Comment: are you saving the path or the whole image as BLOB in your database? The image path is just a string in your database. If you are saving it as BLOB then you need to base64 encode the image first before saving it.

Comment: the data looks something like this `uploads/users/149749517629.png`

Comment: thats why the string is displayed instead of the img.Please base64 the img, you can display the img in the html using <img src="data:image/png;base64,@ViewBag.Logo" class="img-responsive" />

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand that the problem isn't the DB or Ajax...
But the image display in `#coverImage`... Try this.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
  $("#coverImage").attr("src",e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL($("#uploadedCoverImage").files[0]);
```

Comment: mmm. You define `input` as `e.target` above in the code... Just try to use the selector of this input instead.

Comment: OK.. Debug it a little. *«It doesn't work»* isn't very helpfull. Put a `console.log("HELLO");` in the `reader.onload` function. Also console log `$("#uploadedCoverImage").files[0]`.

Comment: On what line?... I have a [demo](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LWqyLe?editors=1010) which works the way I told you... Have a look.

Comment: its pointing on `reader.readAsDataURL($("#uploadedCoverImage").files[0]);` when i `console.log(reader);`

Comment: ohhhh sorry i think i forgot to tell on my question that the image from my db doesn't display on the image src when i reload the page.

Comment: Haa... Really?? lolll --- You just don't have **ANY** code to get the image path from the DB here. There should have some PHP code to do this.

Comment: yeah that's the reason why i use .reload on my ajax success.. to display the the image path from my db to the image src...

Comment: It just reloads the page as it was loaded the first time... Empty... No image information... Look for PHP. You have to do something like `<img id="coverImage" src="<?  echo $imagepath; ?>">` -- How do you expect the script to know if you don't tell ??

Comment: And why do it on reload anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems alright, I would personally put the code below (slightly modified version of yours) inside the success callback of the ajax call instead of reloading the window, anyway, what's the purpose of the reload? If your page is reloaded, then the JavaScript will not execute fully on fast internet connection. If your Ajax call takes a while to complete you might then get the desired functionality otherwise the Ajax will success fast enough to reload the page before the FileReader renders the file for you.

```
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.uploadedCoverImage = $("#uploadedCoverImage");
        reader.onload = function (e) {

           $(reader.uploadedCoverImage).attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```